# How to parse double string with comma?

Tags: c#, formatting

I try to parse value with *comma* into `Double`.

**Example:**

```
var strValue = "-0,246";
double value = 0;
double.TryParse(strValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);
```

result:  `0.`

If i try to use `NumberStyles.Any`, result is **246**.

How to make valid result?

**P.S.** I try to replace *comma* on *dot* at `string`. It works, but i think that it is *complicated solution*.

Comment: "-0,246" cannot be parsed as `InvariantCulture` because it's clearly a culture-specific format. Invariant format uses dot, not comma. You have to use the culture-specific parsing or to convert the string to a culture-invariant format.

Comment: You are using Invariant Culture. Use the culture the string was entered in.

Comment: What culture are you using? InvariantCulture uses the current culture that you machine is set to.  To use a different culture you must specify the language.country that is compatible with the data.

Comment: @jdweng - your statement `InvariantCulture uses the current culture that you machine is set to` is wrong - `InvariantCulture` is always the same on any machine - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture

Comment: @jdweng, my current culture is ru-RU. And when i use 'CurrentCulture' it works well.

Comment: My guess would be you are overthinking your problem - since you are saying your current culture is `ru-RU` and your string is a valid decimal in that culture, what are you actually trying to do? Why do you need the dot?

Comment: As I said the Invariant Culture is dependent on the Machine Settings which is what the link that Rand Random provided.  If you are using data from another culture you cannot use Invariant Culture.

Comment: @jdweng - again you are saying it wrong Invariant Culture is NOT dependent on machine settings - it is `culture-INsensitive` and not `culture-sensitive` - the `InvariantCulture` does not use any Setting on the machine it is ALWAYS the same it is INDEPENDENT of the machine

Comment: The link says following : The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.  So if you are using data from a different English country or a different language then you need to use a different culture.  Which is what I said!!!!

Comment: @jdweng, i manually set culture to en-US

Comment: Is the comma a decimal place or a thousand separator?  If parsing with thousand separator use : System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands

Comment: @jdweng - You said `InvariantCulture uses the current culture` - wrong! - `InvariantCulture` does NOT use `CurrentCulture` - `Invariant Culture is dependent on the Machine Settings` - wrong! - `InvariantCulture` is NOT dependent on the machine settings - I never claimed that your second sentence of your first statement is wrong so this one is correct `To use a different culture you must specify the language.country that is compatible with the data.` but everything you are saying about `InvariantCulture` is just wrong it does neither use current culture nor machine settings!

Comment: So if you are in London and use Invariant Culture will it use a comma or a period for a decimal point?  What about USA?

Comment: @jdweng - `InvariantCulture` is `culture-insensitive` so no matter where you are in the world, no matter what your `CurrentCulture` might be - `InvariantCulture` will always have a dot for the decimal point - thats the whole point of `InvariantCulture` that you can access a culture that is guaranteed to be the same - even the term `Invariant` is saying exactly that, which means in other terms `constant` - https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/invariant

Comment: A totally different thought: Where is that number coming from? Is it a UI-Element? Then right now it's a TextBox or something? How about using a UI-Element that gives you a double right away?

Comment: @Fildor,it is console application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify expected culture format, however you can just specify number separator like that:

```cs
Double.Parse(
   "-0,233", 
    new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) 
    { 
       NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = ","} 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should provide different culture, since in `InvariantCulture`, comma `,` is a *thousand separator* which will be *ignored* when *allowed* (and so you have **-246** in case of `NumberStyles.Any`):

```
  "123,345,789" -> 123456789
```

You can try, say, `CurrentCulture` (if your current culture uses `,` as a decimal separator)

```
double.TryParse(strValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out value);
```

Or put a specific culture, e.g. Russian one:

```
double.TryParse(strValue, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"), out value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NumberFormatInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=netframework-4.8) like this:

```
var strValue = "-0,246";
double value = 0;

// Create a NumberFormatInfo object
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
// Store the current value to restore it later
var currentSeperator = nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator;

// Change the seperator and parse the value
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
value = double.Parse(strValue, nfi);

// Restore the separator
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = currentSeperator;
```

In this example the separator is restored after the value is parsed.

It is nice to put this method in an extension method:

```
class DoubleExtensions
{
    public double ParseToDouble(this string strValue)
    {           
        // Create a NumberFormatInfo object
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;

        // Store the current value to restore it later
        var currentSeperator = nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator;

        // Change the seperator and parse the value
        nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

        try
        {
            if (double.TryParse(strValue, nfi, out var value))
            {
                return value;
            }           
        }
        finally
        {
            // Restore the separator
            nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = currentSeperator;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var strValue = "-0,246";
double value = strValue.ParseToDouble();
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `String.Replace` to eliminate commas in numeric strings:

```
var strValue =" -0,246";
strValue = strValue.Replace(",", ".");
double value=0;
double.TryParse(strValue,NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);
```

Comment: Value would be `-246` in your example

Comment: isn't that what he entered?

Comment: The expected result is `-0.246` (i.e. the russian culture uses `,` as decimal seperator instead as the us one does with `.`)